# Bourne Shell - How to identify that first parameter is ''

Tags: linux, shell, parameters, sh

How can a Bourne Shell script know that the first parameter it received was `''` (Two single quotation marks?

I've tried

```
if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
    echo "Wrong number of parameters"
fi
```

But it seems that the `$1` expands to an empty string and so is `"$1"`.

Comment: Do you *need* this to be `''`? Passing `"''"` should work, then.

Comment: I'd _like_ it to be '', so that users of both Linux and Windows versions of the same script will use the same parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you type '' in command line shell translate it to argument - zero length string.
Check variable that holds the number or arguments (before checking -z "$1").

```
# check for any arguments
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; ...
# or -- has arguments and first one is ''
if [ "$#" -gt 0 -a -z "$1" ]; ...
```

See 'man test' for INTEGER comparison tests (-eq, -gt, etc).

EDIT (based on comments to question):

On windows (what shell do you use?) you have to check for '' (two characters) (cmd.exe passes it that way I think). On linux your script get an argument of string length zero.

if [ \( "$#" -gt 0 -a -z "$1" \) -o "$1" = "''" ]; ...

Comment: So you're saying that the script can't know if it got '' or an empty string, because '' is "translated" prior to invocation?

Comment: Yes, on Linux shells do argument handling/quoting/etc. In your script it's impossible to detect if user types "" or ''. And you can only detect if there is zero length argument or no argument at all by looking at argument counter ($#).

Comment: Thanks, I guess your solution is most suitable for me right now.

Comment: @kupson It is not true that you must check $# to know if an empty argument was passed.  ${1?Unset} will exit the script if no argument is passed but not if the empty string is passed, and ${1+set} will be 'set' if an empty argument is passed but the empty string otherwise.

Comment: @WilliamPursell After all it looks like bash 4.1.5 and dash 0.5.5 can't tell the difference in ${1:-x} (or ':?x' ':+x') between "" and not passing an argument.

Comment: @kupson  The colon is significant.  ':-' means "is unset or empty", while '-' means "is unset".

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you :) My man bash page say nothing about forms without ':' and I have trouble finding them in http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters. Documentation bug or I'm blind?

Comment: @kupson Look at section 2.6.2 at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18

Answer (score 3):

I assume what you mean is that *a parameter was passed, but its value is empty*. This is how to check it:

```
if [ $# -gt 0 -a "$1" = '' ]
then
    echo '$1 was passed, but empty'
fi
```

If you want to check *how many parameters were passed* (empty or not), then use `$#` (argument count):

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo 'no parameters were passed'
fi
```

If you want to check the difference between two *double* quotation marks (`""`) and *single* quotation marks (`''`), there's no way to do that in Bourne shell alone. By the time your code is executed, these strings have been evaluated to the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

`''` is obviously not an empty string; it contains two characters. Do

```
[ "$1" = "''" ]
```

But then, on the (Linux) command line, you'll have to pass the parameter as

```
./script.sh "''"
```

Comment: If I echo "$1" I still get the empty string, why would the comparison work? Also I suspect you intended to use `==`

Comment: `=` should do fine for string comparison. If `$1` is the empty string, this will obviously return false.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ "$1" == "--" ] ; then
     echo "Wrong number of parameters"
fi
```